# writing node.js get handler with parameters?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express

How do I write a get handler for the following URL with node.js?

`http://localhost:3000/auth?code=xxxxxxx`

The following code did not work

```
app.get('/auth', function (req,res) {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because it doesn't do anything. You need to send a response:

```
app.get('/auth', function (req,res) {
    res.send('Hi it worked. Code: ' + req.query.code);
});
```

Another way to do it would be like this:

```
app.get('/auth/:code', function (req,res) {
    res.send('Hi it worked. Code: ' + req.params.code);
});
```

and the URL would simply be `http://localhost:3000/auth/xxxxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, some client sides should accept a certain response type.
For instance, you should send a JSON object as a response.

So, rather than just responding a string, it is better if you send a JSON object as:

```
app.get('/auth', function (req,res) {
    res.send({ 'response' : 'Hi it worked.', 'code': req.query.code });
});
```